Returning result from one column if criteria are met in multi columns / rows
I have a spreadsheet where some equipment checks are done. There are 11 columns/checkpoints and one with the issue description. If the checkpoint is checked and there's no problem, then the operator puts " OK " in the row "OK" If something is wrong, then "NOK" and column 12 puts a short issue description.
enter image description here
I need the formula to search for example rows with the week number 33, check if there is any "NOK" record, return the number of "NOK" and return the description.
I was trying to use IFERROR but even when NOK is present, it still returns "No NOK found for Week 33" Please see the formula below:
=IFERROR(INDEX(O2:O22, MATCH(1, (B2:B22=33) * (D2:N22="NOK"), 0)), "No NOK found for Week 33")

